# Use scanf() to input to multiple variables?

Tags: c, scanf

I am wondering if it is possible to use scanf() to read one line (actually just 1 digit from 0 to 9) and input the data as both a char variable and an integer variable so the user only has to enter the number once. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am writing in C, using nano as my text editor, gcc as my compiler, and Ubuntu 12.04 as my OS. I also have access to Windoze, if necessary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the integer in with `scanf` and then convert it to a character by adding `'0'`.  Since digits are always represented sequentially, this will convert any *single digit* integer to its corresponding character value.

```
int i;

do {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if (i < 0 || i > 9)
        printf("Please try again (number must be between 0 and 9)\n");
} while (i < 0 || i > 9);

char c = i + '0';

// now i has the number and c has the character
printf("%d %c\n", i, c); // outputs, e.g., 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to take the variable in twice, you want to use a *cast* or *type conversion*.

Read the variable as a character, check if it is between `'0'` and `'9'` (character zero and character nine), and if it is, cast it to an `int` like so: `int x = (int)(my_character-'0');`.

If you want to be very safe or need more-than-one-character strings, see the `atoi` function.